# Why must two integral domains with $17$ elements be isomorphic?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Why is it true that two integral domains with $17$ elements must be isomorphic to one another?

I was studying quotient fields when I saw this question.

Comment: Because they are isomorphic to the field $\mathbb{F}_{17}$.

Comment: Finite rings are integral domains iff they are fields.  And there is only one field of order $17$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $D$ be a domain with $17$ elements.

Consider the canonical ring homomorphsim $\phi: \mathbb Z \to D$ given by $n \mapsto n\cdot 1_D$.

Since $1 \ne 0$ in $D$, $1$ must have additive order $17$, because its additive order divides $17$, which is prime. This means that $\ker\phi = 17\mathbb Z$ and so $D \cong  \mathbb Z / (17)$.

Comment: Can I use the same method to prove that no one integral domain can have 10 elements?
I mean, establishing $\phi : Z \to D$ then $\ker \phi = 10\mathbb{Z}$ and then
$$\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{10Z} \cong D$$

Comment: That's what I've added in an answer to your previous question.